# Write a program which tells the number of days in a month. consider leap year

Tags: javascript

I want to write a script in Js which tells number of days in a month and the test case must satisfy the below:

Enter a month: January. output->
January has 31 days.

Enter a month: JANUARY output->
January has 31 day

Enter a month: February output->
February has 28 days.

Enter a month: FEbruary output->
February has 28 days.

and my code is:

```
let a = prompt('Enter the month:');

let b = a.charAt(0).toUpperCase();

let c = a.slice(1, a.length).toLowerCase();

let Month = (b + c);

if ('January' === Month || 'March' === Month || 'May' === Month || 'July' === Month || 'Agust' === Month || 'October' === Month || 'December' === Month) {
console.log(`${Month} has 31 days`)
}
else if ('February' === Month) {
console.log(`${Month} has 28 days`);
} 
else if ('April' === Month || 'June' === Month || 'September' === Month || 'November' === Month) {
   console.log(`${Month} has 30 days`)
}
else{
console.log('Re-Enter');
}
```

It satisfies only first test case anybody help me out with the correct logic which satisfies all the test cases.

Comment: What does it do for the cases it fails, and why does it do that?

Comment: Why not do a tolowercase on your month and compare it with a lowercase month rather than trying to uppercase the first letter?

Comment: This code works for me?

Comment: I tested your code and it is working properly as you expected. Are you running your code correctly? Could you provide me with HTML Code?

Comment: Your code works fine despite it can be improved: anyway the only point of failure is when you check for August (you wrote 'Agust') instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it this way.

We can define two different variables that receive data from the user (month, year). For the ***month*** variable, the rules of the word are clear; The first letter must be uppercase, the remaining letters must be lowercase. Even if the user does not enter a value according to this rule, we can make it what we want by applying methods to the variable month.

Then we can calculate the leap year according to the ***year*** variable we receive. I solved this situation by writing an if-else structure that calculates leap year for values where month value is February within the switch case structure.

[If you want to learn math about leap year, you can read this article](https://airandspace.si.edu/stories/editorial/science-leap-year#:%7E:text=For%20this%20reason%2C%20not%20every,skipped%20is%20the%20year%202100.)

```
let month = prompt("Enter a month: ");
let year = parseInt(prompt("Enter a year: "));
month = month[0].toUpperCase() + month.slice(1).toLowerCase();
switch (month) {
  case "January":
  case "March":
  case "May":
  case "July":
  case "August":
  case "October":
  case "December":
    console.log(`${month} has 31 days in ${year}.`);
    break;
  case "April":
  case "June":
  case "September":
  case "November":
    console.log(`${month} has 30 days in ${year}.`);
    break;
  case "February":
    if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0) {
      console.log(`${month} has 29 days in ${year}.`);
      break;
    } else {
      console.log(`${month} has 28 days in ${year}.`);
      break;
    }
  default:
    alert("Please enter a valid month name!");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can <strike>calculate</strike> retrieve the number of days for a month in any year by retrieving the date value of a `Date` for *the next month* with a date value of **0**. Here's a small factory to determine the numbers of day per month (numeric or using a month name):

```js
const getNDaysForMonthFactory = _ => {
  const months = (`january,february,march,april,may,june,`+
    `july,august,september,october,november,december`).split(',');
  const byNr = (year, month) => new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  
  return {
    byNr, 
    byName: (year, month) => {
      const m = months.findIndex( m => m === month.toLowerCase());

      return m > -1 
        ? byNr(year, m + 1) 
        : `[${month}] is not a valid month`;
      },
   };
}

const {byNr, byName} = getNDaysForMonthFactory();

console.log(`(byNr) 6 2022: ${byNr(2022, 6)} days`);
console.log(`(byNr) 2 2022: ${byNr(2022, 2)} days`);
console.log(`(byNr) 2 2000: ${byNr(2000, 2)} days`);
console.log(`(byName) february 2000: ${byName(2000, `FEBRuary`)} days`);
console.log(`(byName) nothing 2022: ${byName(2022, `nothing`)}`);

// so
showDays();
document.addEventListener(`change`, handle);
document.addEventListener(`keyup`, handle);

function showDays() {
    const [month, year] = [
      +document.querySelector(`#month`).value,
      +document.querySelector(`#year`).value ];
    document.querySelector(`#nDays`).textContent = 
      `${byNr(year, month)} days`;
}

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === `year` || evt.target.id === `month`) {
    return showDays();
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="month">
  <option value="1" selected>January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="3">March</option>
  <option value="4">April</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">June</option>
  <option value="7">July</option>
  <option value="8">August</option>
  <option value="9">September</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
  <option value="11">November</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select> 
<input id="year" type="number" value="2022"> <span id="nDays"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of @KooiInc response without the while loop

```js
const getNDays = (year, month) => {
  let daysOfMonth = 0;
  let date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0));
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
  
  
  return date.getDate();
}

console.log(`june 2022: ${getNDays(2022, 6)} days`);
console.log(`february 2022: ${getNDays(2022, 2)} days`);
console.log(`february 2000: ${getNDays(2000, 2)} days`);
console.log(`february 1900: ${getNDays(1900, 2)} days`);

// so
showDays();
document.addEventListener(`change`, handle);

function showDays() {
    const [month, year] = [
      +document.querySelector(`#month`).value,
      +document.querySelector(`#year`).value ];
    document.querySelector(`#nDays`).textContent = 
      `${getNDays(year, month)} days`;
}

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === `year` || evt.target.id === `month`) {
    return showDays();
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="month">
  <option value="1" selected>January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="3">March</option>
  <option value="4">April</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">June</option>
  <option value="7">July</option>
  <option value="8">August</option>
  <option value="9">September</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
  <option value="11">November</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select> 
<input id="year" type="number" value="2022"> <span id="nDays"></span>
```

Comment: You're right, loop is overcomplicating things

Answer (score 0):

We can create a `formatDaysInMonth()` function that will take a monthName such as January, FEBRUARY, etc and a year and return the formatted month and days, like "February 2020 has 29 days":

```js
function monthNameToMonth(monthName) {
  const months = { january: 1, february: 2, march: 3, april: 4, may: 5, june: 6, july: 7, august: 8, september: 9, october: 10, november: 11, december: 12 };
  return months[monthName.toLowerCase()]
}

function getDaysInMonth(year, month) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();  
}

function formatDaysInMonth(year, monthName) {
  let month = monthNameToMonth(monthName);
  let days = getDaysInMonth(year, month);
  monthName = monthName.toUpperCase().slice(0,1) + monthName.toLowerCase().slice(1);
  return `${monthName} ${year} has ${days} days`;
}

let monthName = prompt('Enter the month name:');
let year = prompt('Enter the year:');
console.log(formatDaysInMonth(year, monthName))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: 2 2024 returns `NaN` days ...

Comment: The user specifies the month name, such as February....